# How to display Czech characters in dialog window (Visual Studio C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, character-encoding

I am using Visual Studio 2010 C++ (Windows XP).

I have defined resource in common.rc:

```
    #include "../res/resource.h"

#define WINVER 0x0400
#include <Winresrc.h>
#define IDC_STATIC -1

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Czech (Czech Republic) resources

LANGUAGE LANG_CZECH, SUBLANG_DEFAULT


IDD_TERRAIN_2 DIALOG DISCARDABLE  0, 0, 280, 136
STYLE WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION
CAPTION "Map/Terrain°Čeština"
FONT 8, "MS Sans Serif"
BEGIN    
    GROUPBOX        "°",IDC_STATIC,2,3,291,34
    LTEXT           "Map Size (square):",IDC_STATIC,10,16,60,8
    COMBOBOX        IDC_TR_SIZE,72,14,62,70,CBS_DROPDOWN | WS_TABSTOP
    LTEXT           "AI Type:",IDC_STATIC,150,16,28,8
      COMBOBOX      IDC_TR_AITYPE,181,14,94,72,CBS_DROPDOWNLIST | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
```

END

The main thing I need to display is character "°" but I have added some Czech text to caption: "Map/Terrain°Čeština"

This is what is displayed:
[image]

I have set Project Properties/Conf./General/Project Defaults/Character Set to Multibyte.

I have tried to read the common.rc to the project. Files are having UTF8 character set.

I have changed two responsible functions MAKEINTRESOURCE to MAKEINTRESOURCEA:

```
pg.pszTemplate = MAKEINTRESOURCEA(IDD_MSGS + i);
```

and

```
pg.pszTemplate = MAKEINTRESOURCEA(IDD_MSGS + (PAGES_NO_CHANGE+i) );
```

But still it is displayed wrong. What else can I do to get correct display of characters in dialog box?

You can check the project here:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/autots/files/C%2B%2B/aokts-1.0.1%20r72c%20update_test.new.zip/download

Comment: Could you try changing the strings to wchar? e.g.:
 `CAPTION L"Map/Terrain°Čeština"`

Comment: Yes but the result is same